# Typescript type for alphanumeric and special characters

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I need to define a type for a response which looks like:

```
TYGOokcgyA9-FQZPM7-evpely6ETEnLyU2yq6hTD_XpTWkPckEP5bFm79hUTtE7rpa6Aiqc6s7xcTXQNNLSClTWtmc7uMIhf-44r3W3d7qY_LkhkGKuv
```

what type can I use in Typescript for this ?

```
export interface key {
  key:{what type should go over here?}
}
```

Comment: Did you consider `string`?

Comment: since it's a chain of character, maybe a string ?

Comment: String does not satisfy your requirement?

Comment: nope, `Type 'key' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so called [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) in Typescript that let you define more strictly what kind of value the string may have.
However, I think in your case that would just become too complicated.

Why not define it as a simple `string` and take a look at [Regular Expressions (regex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)?

With regexes you can verify if a string matches a certain pattern so you could verify its validity before creating the object holding the key or before using it (depends on the context).

Comment: is there a "template literal type" for `base64url` (which is what the string looks like) - i.e. base64 with `=` remove, `+` => `-` and `/` => `_`